# ElasticSearch 7.10 AWS Reindexing error es_rejected_execution_exception 429

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

Both my indices are on the same node. The source has about 200k documents, I'm using AWS and the instance type is "t3.small.search" so 2 vCPUs. I tried slicing already but it just gives me the same error. Any ideas on what I can do to make this process finish successfully?

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "es_rejected_execution_exception",
        "reason" : "rejected execution of coordinating operation [shard_detail=[fulltext][0][C], shard_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=0, shard_operation_bytes=98296362, shard_max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=105630] OR [node_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=0, node_replica_bytes=0, node_all_bytes=0, node_operation_bytes=98296362, node_max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=105630924]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "es_rejected_execution_exception",
    "reason" : "rejected execution of coordinating operation [shard_detail=[fulltext][0][C], shard_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=0, shard_operation_bytes=98296362, shard_max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=105630] OR [node_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=0, node_replica_bytes=0, node_all_bytes=0, node_operation_bytes=98296362, node_max_coordinating_and_primary_bytes=105630924]"
  },
  "status" : 429
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem. I was trying to reindex a couple of indices that had a lot of documents in them. I raised the JVM HeapSize from 512mb to 2gb and it fixed the problem.

Check current JVM HeapSize:
GET {ES_URL}/_cat/nodes?h=heap*&v

Here's how you can change the settings: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/advanced-configuration.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).